# Line tangent to circle inside an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

If you take a circle enclosed inside an isosceles triangle, and then draw a line which is tangent to the circle and which intersects with the two equal sides, is that line parallel to the triangle's third line?

Here is an image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV2DB.png].

If the answer is yes, then is it also true if the tangent line was draw between two non-equal sides?

Comment: Take the tangent a little to the right of the one drawn.

Comment: @AndréNicolas means that your tangent line is not well-defined: there are infinitely many of them, and only one is parallel to the third side. Also, you would do better to use a diagram with a triangle that is not equilateral.